# How to remove word from string separated by commas

Tags: php

I am trying to give my user the ability to add and remove items from a list.
the list is formatted like this: `item1,item2,item3` each item is separated by a comma, except the last item does not end with one and the first does not start with one.
So when my user wants to remove and item for example `item3` I need PHP to remove it and the comma before it. If they wanted to remove `item2` I need it to also remove the comma before it and the item. If the user wants to remove `item1` i need to to remove the item and the comma after it.

Im not using an array because Im storing the the list in a mysql database

This is the code that I've been trying to get to work. It works for every item except for item 1, when I try to remove `item1` it can't find it because it is looking for the starting comma not the trailing one.

```
$skills = 'item1,item2,item3,item4';
$skillToRemove = 'item1';
if(strpos($skills, $skillToRemove . ',') == 1)
    $newSkills = str_replace(',' . $skillToRemove, '', $skills);
else
    $newSkills = str_replace($skillToRemove . ',', '', $skills);
echo $newSkills;
```

Comment: Can you tell what business logic represents your list? What you try to store at db in this string? It should be tags, like on stackoverflow: php,mysql,sql. Or free car places at parking, or else etc

Answer (score 3):

Learn to work with arrays

```
$skills = 'item1,item2,item3,item4';
$skillToRemove = 'item1'

$skillArray = explode(',', $skills);
$findSkill = array_search($skillToRemove, $skillArray);
if ($findSkill !== false)
    unset($skillArray[$findSkill];
$skills = implode(',', $skillArray);
```

Comment: sorry I should have stated Im not using an array because Im storing the list in a database

Comment: Your're storing a comma separated list in a database!!!! Then you will have loads of problems like this.... use databases properly, normalize the data, and databases become your .... store comma separated lists in a database, and you're making a lot of extra work for yourself

Comment: @JamieThirkell ^^ I would recommend you to normalize your db to normalization level 3.

Comment: And it's also worth noting that using arrays doesn't preclude you from using a database, and while it won't make life easier than a properly normalized database, it's still a lot easier using arrays than your inordinately complex string manipulation

Comment: how should I store them then?

Comment: @JamieThirkell I think you want to read [**this**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)!

Comment: and if I store an array in a database it will show as `array`

Comment: No it won't, not in a properly normalized database, don't try to store an array in a database as though it was a string..... LEARN TO USE A DATABASE PROPERLY AND IT WILL BE YOR FRIEND

Answer (score 2):

Please don't use a string! Put your items into an array and if you need to print it use [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php). But just put your items into an array like this:

```
<?php

    $skills = ["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"];
    $skillToRemove = 'item1';
    unset($skills[array_search($skillToRemove, $skills)]);

?>
```

And if you want to print your list just do this:

```
echo implode(",", $skills);
```

Comment: ^^ Whenever you find yourself working with a _list_ or _collection_ of something, you should be manipulating it as an array. A comma-separated string should be thought of as an _output_ format for presentation, not a data manipulation or storage format.

Comment: sorry I should have stated Im not using an array because Im storing the list in a database

Comment: @JamieThirkell See [Mark Baker's comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29450387/how-to-remove-word-from-string-separated-by-commas/29450432?noredirect=1#comment47066792_29450450)!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to remove the selected skill and [trim](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) away any leftover comma, using this:

```
$newSkills = trim(
    preg_replace("/((?<=^)|(?<=,))\\Q$skillToRemove\\E(,|$)/", "", $skills),
    ","
);
```

Regular expression explained:

```
/                     Begin pattern
((?<=^)|(?<=,))       Begin match with start of string (^) or comma.
                      The `?<=` makes sure this is will not be replaced.
\Q                    Begin quote skill string. Any characters between \Q and \E
                      including metacharacters (e.g. '+' or '.') will be treated
                      as literals.
$skillToRemove        Match skill to remove (will be removed)
\E                    End of skill string quoting
(,|$)                 Followed by comma or end of string (will also be removed)
/                     End pattern
```

Example:

```
$skills = 'item1,item2,item3,item4';
$skillToRemove = 'item4';
$newSkills = trim(
    preg_replace("/((?<=^)|(?<=,))\\Q$skillToRemove\\E(,|$)/", "", $skills),
    ","
);
echo "Removed item4: ", $newSkills, PHP_EOL;
```

Output:

```
Removed item4: item1,item2,item3
```

Comment: Devil's advocate says: "If `$skillToRemove` contains `\E`, then your pattern logic will be broken."  `preg_quote()` is the reliable solution.

Comment: Wast underrated answer!